# Google sheet formula =$G1=

Tags: google-sheets, custom-formatting

I am trying to go get the conditional formatting to color the entire line, based on a text answer.

I have used "custom formula is" and `=$G1=TRUE` before, where I have a tickbox, so I tried to change the formula to `=$G1=JA` but this did not work.

I have a drop-down menu in column G with options `JA - NEI - KANSKJE` that I want to use the formula on, to color out the entire line.

I want green lines if `JA`, red lines if `NEI` etc.

**Note**: the words are yes, no & maybe in Norwegian

Answer (score 1):

Try

=$G1="JA"

and see if that works?